# mongodb connection error when trying to fetch data

Tags: php, mongodb, error-handling

This is my login function.
My problem is whenever I try sending a query to the DB, I get a false result ("salah").

Why is does the fetch here always return `false`?

What do I need to do for the code to read `true`?

Here is my code:

```php
$koneksi = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017/");

$database = $koneksi->marketplace;
$collection = $database->selectCollection("admin");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $data = array(
        "username" => $user,
        "password" => $pass,
    );

    $fetch = $collection->findOne($data);

    if($fetch) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $fetch['username'];

        header('Location: ../views/index.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "salah";
    }
}
```

Comment: you should echo the error results when the fetch fails. That would help a lot with debugging. If the error you get doesn't help you fix it alone, you are always welcome to edit the question and post the error. Without it, it's way harder to tell what the problem is

Comment: Are you sure that fetch is an array ? MongoDB give by default an object ($fetch->username). Second point : are you sure the password is in clear in BDD ? If yes, it's not a good idea ; the password need to be stored hashed and salted